# Pagedown package error in producing the output

Tags: r, r-markdown, pagedown

I have recently decided to use `pagedown` package in producing pdf and html outputs and therefore installed the library. I am trying to run the very simple Rmd file that comes as default when I choose to use `pagedown` file as my new file in the RStudio.

Here is the Rmd file content if you would like to see;

````
---
title: "A Multi-page HTML Document"
author: "Yihui Xie and Romain Lesur"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pagedown::html_paged:
    number_sections: FALSE
# uncomment this line to produce HTML and PDF in RStudio:
knit: pagedown::chrome_print 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Introduction

This is an example of a multi-page HTML document with some options shown in YAML header. See https://pagedown.rbind.io for the full documentation. The rest of this document is random text.

# Random text

```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
random_markdown = function(len = 100) {
  uri = knitr::image_uri(file.path(R.home('doc'), 'html', 'logo.jpg'))
  text = function(len) {
    trimws(paste(sample(c(letters, rep(' ', 10)), len, TRUE), collapse = ''))
  }
  id = function() paste(sample(letters, 8, TRUE), collapse = '')
  figure = function(i = id()) {
    sprintf('![(#fig:%s)The R logo.](%s){width=%d%%}', i, uri, sample(20:60, 1))
  }
  tab = paste(knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:5])), collapse = '\n')
  table = function(i = id()) {
    c(sprintf('Table: (#tab:%s)A table example.', i), tab)
  }
  unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
    if (i %% 20 == 0) return(paste('#', text(sample(10:30, 1))))
    if (i %% 10 == 0) return(paste('##', text(sample(10:30, 1))))
    # insure some elements
    if (i == 3) return(text(50))
    if (i == 4) return(figure("md-fig"))
    if (i == 5) return(text(50))
    if (i == 6) return(table("md-tab"))
    # then random
    type = sample(1:3, 1, prob = c(.9, .03, .07))
    switch(type, text(sample(50:300, 1)), figure(), table())
  }))
}
cat(random_markdown(), sep = '\n\n')


# Knitr inserted Figures and tables

## Simple graphics
```
````

Until here, R markdown can run the document well. However, when I tried to add the following two code chunks, the document fails to run.

````
``` {r simple-graphic, fig.cap = 'A very simple plot'}
plot(1)
```

## Simple tables

```{r simple-table}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars, 3), caption = "A Simple table")
```
````

And here is the error I get;

```
Error in force(expr) : Failed to generate output in 30 seconds (timeout).
Calls: <Anonymous> -> with_temp_loop_maybe -> with_loop -> force
Closing websocket connection
Closing browser
Cleaning browser working directory
Closing local webserver
```

I do not understand why the document does not fail to run in the first phase, while it fails to run in the second step. I tried to find a solution through web. I hope I am clear regarding my problem and I look forward to your reply. Thank you for your understanding beforehand.

Comment: I ran your codes successfully, even with the second step.

Answer (score 0):

If you just remove `knit: pagedown::chrome_print`  the document will render to HTML just fine, Then from here, you can `"print to PDF"` from the browser to get both an HTML and a PDF doc of the output

```
---
title: "A Multi-page HTML Document"
author: "Yihui Xie and Romain Lesur"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pagedown::html_paged:
    number_sections: FALSE
---
```

I think the issue might be your are specifying 2 different output formats, and Rmarkdown is taking a long time to render these

There is a similar issue discussed [here](https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown/issues/157) the advice was to increase the `timeout` value, as it's default is 30 seconds until the process is fails out. and another similar issue [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/not-able-to-produce-paged-pdf-document-when-trying-to-render-html-paged-rmarkdown-document-using-parameters/80677)... but to be honest, I was not able to correct apply the `timeout` argument in `chrome_print`
[image]